# IDE for ASP.NET Core development on Linux

Tags: linux, ide, visual-studio

My team wants to move from ASP.NET Core development on Windows to Linux. Obviously we use Visual Studio right now, so the bar is set very high.

I need a Linux IDE that can handle this well... well enough for a work environment, not a hobby project.

If you do *work-related* ASP.NET Core development on Linux, please let me know your IDE and setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the only solution that you can create ASP.NET projects on Linux is [MonoDevelop](https://kubadownload.com/monodevelop-download.1343.html). How to install the software can be found [here](http://www.monodevelop.com/download/linux/). Xamarin Studio was a much better solution, but it is no longer developed. The last version is 6.4. Now Xamarin is included in Visual Studio.

> MonoDevelop enables developers to quickly write desktop and web
>   applications on Linux, Windows and Mac OS. It also makes it easy for
>   developers to port .NET applications created with Visual Studio to
>   Linux and Mac OS maintaining a single code base for all platforms.
>   MonoDevelop is now a part of Microsoft Xamarin Studio.

JetBrains offers a variety of tools to create .Net Technologies apps. You can find all product on the official [webpage](https://www.jetbrains.com/products.html#tech=dotnet).  For exmample JetBrains Rider supports .NET Framework, the new cross-platform .NET Core, and Mono based projects. This lets you develop a wide array of applications including .NET desktop applications, services and libraries, Unity games, Xamarin apps, ASP.NET and ASP.NET Core web applications.

Comment: Have you used it with ASP.NET Core? If so, would you recommend it for a large project?

Comment: There is no doubt what is the best ASP.NET development platform, and you are already using it. I would recommend to stay where you are if your business is based on it. 

If your projects are not to complex maybe an option to choose will be free [Visual Studio Code](https://kubadownload.com/visual-studio-code-download.1246.html).  Check [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app-xplat/) page for some tutorials how to Create an ASP.NET Core MVC app with Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Yeah VS is the best! It's hard to move to Linux just because of it. There's a replacement for everything we use every day, EXCEPT for VS! VsCode is nice, but it's very lightweight compared to VS... It looks like the best option in Linux right now.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [Jetbrains Rider](https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/). It workers on Windows, Mac and Linux. It supports most .NET frameworks, including .NET Core and Mono. It does cost money though. Their basic business subscription cost $349.00 for the first year, $279.00 for the second, then $209.00 for the third and beyond. However their individual costs less, $139.00 for the first year, $111.00 for the second, then $83.00 for the third and beyond.

Comment: Have you used it with ASP.NET Core? If so, would you recommend it for a large project?

Comment: I will be honest. I have not, but I have used multiple Jetbrains products and would recommend them for any large projects.

Comment: Yeah Jetbrains rocks. Though VS is free, so it's a hard sell... :)